# Adding 1 InnoDB table to a DB full of MyISAM tables (effects)

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, myisam

We have a database full of MyISAM tables. The thing is that we need transactions on just 1 table, called `payments` My question is, will that work? I mean by changing the engine of that table to `InnoDB` and using transactions on php, will that do the work? or do i have to mess around and do more than just that? Will that affect my db in anyway? The table is isolated, it doesn't have foreign keys  since `MyISAM` doesn't support them.

Ty in advance.

Comment: Just release that changes made inside a transaction, to non-transactional tables, such as `MyISAM`, will be committed, regardless of any `ROLLBACK`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [Storage Engines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/storage-engines.html):

> It is important to remember that you are not restricted to using the same storage engine for an entire server or schema: you can use a different storage engine for each table in your schema.

So yes, your proposal will work (provided that you only wish to attain ACID compliance on the `payments` table, of course).

Comment: So mysql/php will know how to handle that table and it'll do transactions without issues?

Comment: @DeusDeceit: MySQL will, yes.  Of course you will, as usual, have to tell MySQL when you are beginning a transaction and when you wish for the transaction to be committed/rolled-back.  MySQLi and PDO both enable you to do so from their APIs; whereas the ancient (and now deprecated) `ext/mysql`, which you shouldn't be using now anyway, does not - one would have to perform transaction operations through SQL.

Comment: That raises another question. I wasn't part of the development team, I just came on board. The thing is that I AM using PDO in my projects, but they made that project with the old mysql API. The new question is, will it have any effects if I do my part on PHPs with `PDO` when they are doing the rest with pure `mysql` API? is that safe?

Comment: @DeusDeceit: It's safe, provided that one realises the respective operations will be performed over different database connections (and therefore that any `SESSION` state will not be preserved).  I'd strongly encourage them to move everything on to PDO.

Comment: The thing is that this is minor change, I agree that they should move it to PDO, but what they have already works fine for them. The changes I will add will be in separate `PHPs` from theirs, so there wont be any connection problem. I think I learned what I needed,  and I can start applying it. Thumbs up, and ty.